# PlantUML - Long description with nest brackets

Tags: plantuml

I'm trying to draw a long description square with nested components.

Something like

```
node mynode [
<<device>>
--
long description here
] {
    artifact "a nested element"
}
```

The processor give me error until I remove the long description bracket (or viceversa, I decide to remove the nested element). Therefore, if both elements are presents, some problems occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If simple text long description is enough, then you can just put description in quotation marks and use alias:

```
database "Some long description" as oracle1 {
  storage data
}
actor user 
user --> oracle1
```

[image: Rendered diagram]

If more complex description is required then you can use nested diagrams. But in this case you can't link elements of nested diagrams with elements of the outer diagram.

```
rectangle rect1 [
Long long description
---
Some more
===
{{
  rectangle nested1
  rectangle nested2
  nested1 --> nested2
}}
]
rectangle rect2

rect1 ---> rect2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
@startuml
node "<<device>>\n----\nlong description here" as mynode {

artifact "a nested element"
}
@enduml
```

[image]